# How to display a custom validation message depending on whether the list is null or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a newbie in C# and MVC. So, I am using Database First approach for a Player-Team problem. This is a part of automatically generated code for a view related to creating a player:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("TeamID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

A player can only be created if a team exists, and the choices are displayed as a drop down menu. I need to display a warning or notification to the user to create a team first, if there is none, and also provide a link to the page for team creation. 
Is it possible to display such a custom validation message along with the link in it, by just modifying the `.cshtml` file?

Comment: see MVC's remote validations. they will serve your purpose

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you have following options

1. Create a property in your View model `public bool TeamExists{get;set;}`
   while returning Model to View you can set this property in model to `true` if no team exits
2. Create a Variable in your razor view 
   `@{ var TeamExists = Model.Teams ! = null && Model.Teams.count>0 ?null:"active"}`
   in your HTML view you can use this information to display

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='well'>
<span class="label-info @TeamExists ">Add Team first</span>
</div>
```